# AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'character_set_name'

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am running a python app on GCP app engine which connects to cloud SQL database (mySQL). But there is an error in GCP logs that I am unable to resolve,

```
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py", line 161, in on_connect
    charset_name = conn.character_set_name()
AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'character_set_name'
```

Here is the code I am using to establish connection:

```
def connect_with_connector() -> sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:
    """
    Initializes a connection pool for a Cloud SQL instance of MySQL.

    Uses the Cloud SQL Python Connector package.
    """
    # Note: Saving credentials in environment variables is convenient, but not
    # secure - consider a more secure solution such as
    # Cloud Secret Manager (https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager) to help
    # keep secrets safe.

        instance_connection_name = cinstance_connection_name
        db_user = cdb_user
        db_pass = cdb_pass
        db_name = cdb_name
        ip_type = cip_type

        connector = Connector(ip_type)

        def getconn() -> pymysql.connections.Connection:
            conn: pymysql.connections.Connection = connector.connect(
                instance_connection_name,
                "pymysql",
                user=db_user,
                password=db_pass,
                db=db_name,
            )
            return conn

        pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
            "mysql+pymysql://",
            creator=getconn,
            # ...
        )
        return pool

    # Use the custom engine for SQLAlchemy
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS'] = {
        'creator': connect_with_connector
    }
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Am I missing an argument to the method?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the _complete_ error traceback.  Also, what is `Connector`?